# Select * Except particular properties in Cosmos DB with SQL API

Tags: sql, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

Consider the following, I have a document that looks something like this:

```
"id": 2
"properties": {
    "desired": {
        "Property1": 10,
        "Property2": 1,
        "Property3": 1,
        "$metadata": { 
        ...
        },
        "$version": 53
    }
},
```

I want to get everything from the document EXCEPT `$metadata` and `$version` The obvious solution would be to:

```
SELECT c["Property1"], c["Property2"] .... FROM c where c["id"] = "2"
```

However, my document may expand dynamically, hence why the above is suboptimal. I therefore figured that it may be better to exclude just `$metadata` and `$version`. I looked at different "interesting" solutions here on stackoverflow, amongst which one suggests to create a temporary table.

Unfortunately, the query needs to be very efficient, because I want to reduce the amount of RUs used. Also I really want to avoid handling the exclusion in the code.

Therefore, how do I exclude particular "columns" from my document, without writing an excessively long query, which may include creating temporary tables.

Comment: Have you measured the difference between excluding some columns and returning all? From what I've seen adding more complexity to queries often is more expensive than a slightly larger return payload from a simple query.

Comment: You are correct, the problem then gets transferred to my serverless function, which is billed on compute power :-) Here I would then have to process the return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosmos DB does not support "Project Away". You will need to specify properties to project or use * and return all of them.

Comment: Do you think a stored procedure could solve my issue more elegantly?

Comment: If you had the properties you want vs the properties you don't want in separate hierarchies you could self-join to do a Select * on the one's you want and ignore the ones you don't want. But I don't think this is quite what you're asking for.